# Passing parameters for nested relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having trouble passing parameters
My application that is setup like this:

```
Fact belongs_to Source
Source has_many Facts
```

Source is nested under User in routes

I am using the Facts form to create the Source data. So I have getter and setter methods in the Facts model like this:

```
def source_name
  source.try(:name)
end

def source_name=(name)
  self.source = source.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?
end
```

This is working great, but it is not setting the user_id for the parent User attribute. As a result, sources are created, but they are not associated with the User.

I have a hidden field with user_id in the form, but the user_id is still being set. What is the easiest way to pass and save the user_id so the nested relationship is set?

Here is the create method for the Source controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @source = @user.source.build(params[:source])
...
end
```

Comment: add your create action of your controller in your question

Comment: not sure if I understand correctly but shouldn't you then access or set the source via the user model? Like user.source=xxx

Comment: I have a multi-model form under the Facts model. I've tried setting Sources from the form with regular inputs and using fields_for. I can't seem to get it to store the user_id under either way. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: There's a rails casts with a setup very similar to mine (http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association). But Ryan's is simpler in that it doesn't have a Users model to set at the same time.

Comment: Does a user have a single `Source` or many `Sources`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are creating source directly from the setter method in the Fact model.  Unless you establish the chain by using something like build in the FactController, the user_id will not be set.  What you are doing in SourceController needs to be done in the FactsController too.  Also, it seems that the ids are set only for the immediate parent when you use the build command.  You can try something as below:

```
def create
  @source = current_user.sources.find_or_create_by_name(params["source_name"])
  @fact = @source.facts.build(:user_id  => @source.user_id)
  ....
end
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your user has a single `Source`, try the following as your `create()` method:

```
def create
  @user = User.find params[:user_id]
  @user.source = Source.new params[:source]

  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user, :flash => { :success => "Source updated!" }
  else
    flash[:error] = "Failed to update the source!"
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

Creating the `Source` as an attribute on the `User` object and then saving the `User` object should automatically associate the `Source` with the `User`.